# Executing dynamically injected <SCRIPT>s not working on Firefox (47.0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, code-injection, script-tag

I have a HTML snippet returned from an AJAX call of the form

```
<SCRIPT src="..."  type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 function showForumGrid()
 { ... };
 function f()
 { ...}
</SCRIPT>
<DIV id="div1">
 ...
  <IMG id="dummyBody" src="..." onload="showForumGrid()">
</DIV>
```

In the AJAX call handler I am doing the following

```
var x=document.getElementById(snippet_container_id);

//$(x).html(ajaxData);

var domFragment = $.parseHTML($.trim(ajaxData),document,true);
$(x).empty();
$(x).prepend(domFragment);
```

This is working fine in Chrome but in Firefox I am getting the error ReferenceError: showForumGrid is not defined

Comment: Don't just mix JS and jQuery, this is far from readable.

Comment: How have you included your script? Where is you ajax request in the Page. We need to figure out when is it being triggered so that we can pprovide a solution. Please post you HTML with proper script names and show us the Ajax initiation too..

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you do append your `<script>` nodes in the document, after the document has been parsed, they're not treated as synchronous like they were before.
<sub>(even setting the [`async` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) doesn't work)</sub>.

Here is a simplified example :

```js
var external = document.createElement('script');
var inner = external.cloneNode();
external.src = 'data:application/javascript,console.log("external")';
inner.innerHTML = 'console.log("inner")';

document.head.appendChild(external);
document.head.appendChild(inner);
```

Not sure you can do anything else than waiting for the `load` event <sub>(IE9+ browsers)</sub> of the external `<script>`, or to set a loop checking if `showForumGrid` is defined <sub>(if you need support for older browsers)</sub>.

```js
var external = document.createElement('script');
var inner = external.cloneNode();
external.onload = function() {
  document.head.appendChild(inner)
}
external.src = 'data:application/javascript,console.log("external")';
inner.innerHTML = 'console.log("inner")';
document.head.appendChild(external)
```